# Nested checkboxes in AngularJS resource with external options

Tags: angularjs

I have this data structure, search:

```
{
    id: '1',
    name: 'Foo'
    service_ids:
    [
        3,
        8,
        12
    ]
}
```

I then have another data structure, services, that matches the ids from service_ids above with the below:

```
[
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'Fighter'
    },
    {
        id: 4,
        name: 'Typhoon'
    },
    {
        id: 8,
        name: 'Kung'
    },
    {
        id: 12,
        name: 'Builder'
    }
]
```

I want to display this in a form using AngularJS. The name is fine. I want to display all possible services as checkboxes and if the search has one of the services checked then it is ticked in the checkbox. Something like:

```
<li ng-repeat="search in searches">
    <input ng-model="search.name">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="service in services">
            <input type="checkbox">
            {{service.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I don't know how to link that checkbox to the service_ids and the services. Any help appreciated.

I am using $resource.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Ignore my answer, misread you nesting request.

If anyone needs nesting guidance see below:

The best way to nest in angular that I have found is to create a template which is aware of child items like this:

```
<script type="text/ng-template"  id="tree_item_renderer.html">
 <span>{{tag.Name}}</span>
   <ul ng-show="tag.Children.length > 0">
        <li ng-repeat="tag in tag.Children" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'" ></li>
   </ul>
</script>

<ul class="tag-list">
      <li ng-repeat="tag in tags" ng-include="'tree_item_renderer.html'" ></li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question it should be as easy as:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-model="search.service_ids[service.id]">
```

And you should also get bi-directional binding.

**Updated**

Just realized search.service_ids is an array not a map. So the solution above is not accurate.
You might want instead to use a filter:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="search.service_ids | contains:service.id">
```

Then

```
filter('contains', function() {
    return function(haystack, needle) {
        return haystack.indexOf(needle) >= 0;
    }
});
```